# Access outer class object attribute from inner class (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have the following Outer-Inner class scenario:

```
class Outer:
  def __init__(self,x): self.x = x
  class Inner:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): self.params = kwargs
    def func(self): # Here, somehow, I need x
```

Meaning..

The call will go like this: `Outer(10).Inner().func()`

The above statement should print `10`.

NOTE:

1. Can't use static variables (Since state needs to be saved, i.e,
   `pickle` is required)
2. Tried class within a function, that works, but we can't `pickle` a function (right?)
3. Tried inheritance, but doesn't work !

Is the scenario above possible ?

Comment: "# Here, somehow, I need x" well you can't have it. Nesting classes in Python makes no relation between instances of those classes, it just makes the nested class live in the namespace of the other class. Why are you nesting the classes? This is not a common pattern in Python

Comment: The flow in which I am using this,
When I say Inner(),
It creates various clones of this object,
So I need a fixed value for all these clones,
As I said " class within a function" & " static variables" work,
But I need pickle ! @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: When you say `Inner()` it creates a new object, thats how it always works. What do you mean "class within a variable" exactly? Again, nesting classes serves little purpose

Comment: "class within a function"



def function(x):
  class Inner:
   def func(self): print(x)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga