# How to initialize python object from inner class while inheriting attributes fromouter class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I found a post that asks what I am asking without an answer here [access-outer-class-object-attribute-from-inner-class-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61145591/access-outer-class-object-attribute-from-inner-class-python). Since there didn't seem to be much discussion on it, I figured I would make this post.

Below is a skeleton of what I want to accomplish:

```
class Outer:
    def __init__(self, arg_a, arg_b, arg_c):
        self.arg_a, self.arg_b, self.arg_c = arg_a, arg_b, arg_c
        self.big_matrix = MakeMatrix(arg_a, arg_b, arg_c)
    
    class Inner:
        def __init__(self, arg_x, arg_y, arg_z):
            self.new_attribute = F((use instance of big_matrix from outer class), *args, **kwargs)
        ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    outer_obj = Outer(1, 2, 3)
    inner_obj1 = outer_obj.Inner('x1', 'y1', 'z1')
    inner_obj2 = outer_obj.Inner('x2', 'y2', 'z2')
    inner_obj3 = outer_obj.Inner('x3', 'y3', 'z3')
```

Basically, I want to create one instance of an Outer class, and multiple instances of inner classes that also inherits attributes from the Outer object. I want to do this because the big_matrix attribute is memory dense and I don't want to make N copies of that big_matrix.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Is there a better programming paradigm I can use that will accomplish the same thing, without nested classes?

Comment: Why can't you have two separate classes and pass one to the other?

Comment: note: there's no inheritance relationship between these two classes. one is simply defined inside the other.

Comment: @a_guest Is there a way to "pass by reference" one attribute from an outer object to an inner object? Or for that matter, an object instantiated from a super class to an object from a sub class?

Comment: @Adam.Er8 I am using the word "inheritance" loosely here, with regards to attributes from instances of a nested class retaining attributes from instances of an outer class.

Comment: @user3166083 Python never copies around values, it only assigns names to objects. I.e. if you have `x = expensive_to_compute()` and then do `y = x` this simply makes `y` point to the very same object that `x` points to (i.e. very cheap). The same holds for function calls (including class instantiation) where the parameters names are simply bound to the passed arguments (objects).

Comment: @a_guest The problem isn't that `x = expensive_to_compute()` takes a long time to compute. The problem is that variable x takes up a lot of memory. Setting `y = x` is _fast_ but now I am using twice as much memory as before. I want to avoid this kind of redundancy if possible.

Comment: Create the class inner at same level as class outer, but pass the instance of outer_class to the inner _class as part of the intialization.

Comment: @user3166083 It won't take up any additional memory, save for the additional literal name `y` to be stored. `y = x` makes `y` point to *the very same object* in memory. As I said, no copying is happening here.

Comment: I think @itprorh66 makes a lot of sense. Thanks I think this is the best approach!

Comment: From the previous comment I made, I think this is what @a_guest meant. I just needed it to be spelled out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Commenters @itprorh66 and @a_guest gave me an answer that works best for me. For the sake of others who might be having similar issues, I'll answer my own question showing an implementation that works for my situation.

```
class Outer:
    def __init__(self, args_a, args_b, args_c):
        self.BigMatrix = BigMatrixFunc(args_a, args_b, args_c)
    ...

class Inner:
    def __init__(self, outer_object, *args):
        self.new_attribute = F(outer_object, *args)
    ...


 if __name__ == "__main__":
    outer_obj = Outer(1, 2, 3)
    inner_obj1 = Inner(outer_obj, 'x1', 'y1', 'z1')
    inner_obj2 = Inner(outer_obj, 'x2', 'y2', 'z2')
    inner_obj3 = Inner(outer_obj, 'x3', 'y3', 'z3')
```